# methods with the same soapaction

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I'm doing contract-first development of a SOAP server. The wsdl declares the same soapAction for several methods. Now svcutil produces code that declares the same value for the OperationContractAttribute.Action property of several methods. This causes a runtime error which says that every operation must have a unique action value.

How can I solve this? When I change the value of the Action property my server no longer accepts requests from clients.

**Update**
It turns out that the soapaction has to be unique if the routingstyle is set to soapaction, which is the default. So I tried setting it to RequestElement. Unfortunately, this causes the server to no longer recognize the client's messages. I had hoped that the Routingstyle would only change the server's internal behavior.

Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Thanks, regards, Miel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no solution for this in WCF.

Trying to change the routingstyle as I did, applies to ASMX, not WCF.

A workaround may be possible, but there's no standard solution.

Comment: for me the solution was using asmx